# EVAL() function in Html & JavaScript giving weird results....!

Tags: javascript, html, eval

the below code giving some unexpected results. can anyone tell me the reason or logic behind that?

```
<HTML><body><script type="text/javascript">s="10+10";alert("here 3 : "+eval(s+s+s));alert("here 4 :+eval(s+2));</script></body></HTML>
```

in first alert it's giving `2040` and in second alert it's giving `112`
i'm not able to understand the logic kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is bad practice, howerer to answer your question:

```
`s="10+10"`
```

`s` is now `"10+10"`

`eval(s+s+s)` =>

`eval("10+10"+"10+10"+"10+10")` =>

`eval("10+1010+1010+10")` =>

2040

and:

`eval(s+2)` =>

`eval("10+10"+2)` =>

`eval("10+102")` =>

112

---

what you might have meant is:

`eval(s+"+"+s+"+"+s)`

and

`eval(s+"+2")`

Comment: Eval is not necessarily bad, it's just that in the early days of scripting it was abused.